# Comparing RCUs spent for two different DynamoDB cases

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I currently wish to set up a dynamo db table where I have say cookie names, and usernames. All usernames are unique. Each username has their favorite cookie. For cookie names, we want that to be the partition key. Our end goal is to retrieve the usernames associated with a particular cookie. We have two design options and are curious which to follow.

- Case A: cookies -> partition key, map of usernames -> attribute. So that attribute is called say associate_usernames. We can fetch the associated usernames by fetching for each cookie directly
- Case B: cookies - partition key, usernames -> sort key. Thus we can fetch the associated_cookie names in dynamo db by querying or filtering with the partition key.

We are curious which method consumes the least RCUs and why?

-

NB: After a small dynamo DB test, I found the RCUS to be similar(0.5) when I increased the number of partition key matches to 100, I noticed it to be 1, and for the map remained the same(0.5). Can anyone explain why if they agree this test makes sense too?

Answer (score 0):

Read capacity units will be the same, as both styles will round up to the nearest 4KB.

However, with your first approach, you could end up costing more when editing an item, and you could run the risk of exceeding the 400KB item size limit.

Option B is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the AWS team and answer B seems to be the recommended solution for the following reasons

RCU

Method A- Stores all the associated usernames in a single attribute, retrieving username for a specific cookie name would require reading the entire attribute, and then filtering out the relevant usernames. So, depending on number of users per cookie it could result in a higher RCUs.

Method B- More targeted Query by using partition key to fetch only the relevant (Sort Key)usernames associated with the cookie

WCU

Method A- when adding or updating username for a cookie, you may need to modify the entire associated username attribute, resulting in a higher WCU.
Method B- This method requires updating specific username entry for a given cookie, potentially resulting in a lower WCUs.

Scalability

Method B would be scalable as it allows for more efficient queries, especially if the dataset grows. It aligns with DynamoDB best practices of distributing data evenly across partitions and it can scale more effectively with increasing data and query load

Overall, Method B might be more efficient for your use case but it’s important to test and consider specific needs for your applications based on performance and resource utilization! Helpful Documentation on RCU & WCU: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html